# Cannot use sjcl in Appcellerator Titanium project

Tags: javascript, encryption, titanium-mobile, sjcl

I am trying to encrypt some text with sjcl (Stanford Javascript Crypto Library) in my Titanium (target: iOS and Android) project. I am using the simplest method, with no other options:

```
sjcl.encrypt("mypassword", "mytext");
```

The app just hangs on this line, I get no error or any helpful information. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: did you include the sjcl.js and save all files sjcl.zip in a folder and include in project directory

Comment: Yes I did… on this picture you can see the structure (also some unnecessary parts are left in the package): http://weibezahn.com/sjclscreen.png

Answer (score 0):

The code probably runs fine. However the first algorithm tries to use the PBKDF2 function to create a key from the password. This function is deliberately slow to strengthen the password as passwords generally do not contain enough entropy to be safe for use in encryption. If the (debugging) framework takes a lot of time to execute the underlying hash functions then your application may appear to hang ( check your CPU usage).

The solution is to either lower the amount of iterations that the PBKDF2 takes as input, or to use a Java PBKDF2. Both probably require lower level access to SJCL. Finally, choosing a JavaScript library for encryption on a Java platform will degrade performance enormously. You may want to consider dropping SJCL for this purpose.

Comment: I tried to reduce the number of iterations, but to no avail. Interestingly, if I set the number of iterations on their demo page http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.com/sjcl/demo/ ("strenghten" field) to 10 e.g., the script fails. I also tried to use a direct hexadecimal key so that it does not have to be computed by sjcl but with no success… What I need is basically some very shallow encryption (obfuscation would be enough), since the data is very unlikely to be accessed by anyone who does not know about it, and has not much value. Can you recommend something in javascript for that? Thanks!

Comment: I would not consider SJCL a well established crypto library. Once I started using it it quickly turned out that the AAD data for the CCM mode authenticated encryption was not put in the calculation at all (failure in the convenience libs). Unfortunately I haven't used too many JavaScript crypto API's, mostly because I think that browsers should not perform any kind of cryptography related task (it should be fine in in a trusted application though). As said, it would make more sense to create native functionality for each platform and use that from the JavaScript.

Comment: Im suspicious that performance is an issue, I get sub-second response times using this exact code in a pure browser implementation. The sjcl library is one of the more highly regarded crypto libraries out there though -> http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/ for more info on this

Comment: @JamesWestgate The speed will very much depend on the underlying implementation. That should be fine for most high end desktop browsers - all have much better performance than they used to - but it may still be an issue on e.g. embedded browsers.

Comment: This is a valid point. I guess it's unclear whether the OP had this issue in the dev environment or on a device. I'm doing some work in this area and I'll update when I know more.